# JBoss Error while deploying a CXF JAX-WS Web Service

Tags: maven, jboss, cxf

i am trying to deploy with mvn wildfly:deploy and i am getting the following error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:2.0.2.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project SoapJavaFirstWebService: Failed to execute goal deploy: {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit."SoapJavaFirstWebService-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "SoapJavaFirstWebService-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war"
[ERROR]     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.SoapJavaFirstWebService-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader
[ERROR]     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextException
[ERROR]     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException from [Module "deployment.SoapJavaFirstWebService-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader]"

Below my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.tsdevelopment</groupId>
    <artifactId>SoapJavaFirstWebService</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Simple CXF Java-first SOAP project using Spring configuration</name>
    <description>Simple CXF Java-first SOAP project using Spring configuration</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.15.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.Final</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.2.Final</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>16</source>
                        <target>16</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectNameTemplate>[artifactId]-[version]</projectNameTemplate>
                        <wtpmanifest>true</wtpmanifest>
                        <wtpapplicationxml>true</wtpapplicationxml>
                        <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

And my jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="webservices" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Is that you whole pom.xml, or did you cut away some dependencies? I can see spring-web but no other spring dependencies (ie. spring-core)

Comment: That's the whole xml, the spring dependencies came with the archetype.